# How can I enforce attribute types in a Backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to have a Backbone model with float attributes in it but without worrying too much about variable types.

I would like to encapsulate the value parsing right there in the model so I am thinking of overriding the `set` function:

```
var Place = Backbone.Model.extend({
  set: function(attributes, options) {
    if (!_.isEmpty(attributes.latitude)){
      attributes.latitude == parseFloat(attributes.latitude);
    }
    if (!_.isEmpty(attributes.longitude)){
      attributes.longitude == parseFloat(attributes.longitude);
    }
    Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
  }
});
```

However this seems cumbersome, since I would have a similar logic in the validate method and potentially repeated across multiple models. I don't think the View should take care of these conversions.

So what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a validation plugin for your model so that you can validate the input in a generic fashion.

There are several out there including one that I have written:

- [Backbone.Validator](http://github.com/toddself/Backbone.Validator/)
- [Backbone.Validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation)

Then you don't worry about performing data validation anywhere else - your model does it and sends out and `error` message you can listen for and provide appropriate feedback.

Also, a lat/lng pair can, in rare circumstances, be an integer, such as Greenwich England: 0,0 or the north pole: 90,180. And since JavaScript only has "number" any valid input for parseFloat is also valid for parseInt.

But parseFloat will always return a float.

Comment: If you need a more lightweight solution, try my little lib https://github.com/romansky/backbone-typed

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to replace `Backbone.Model.prototype.set` with a preprocessor proxy:

```
/**
 * Intercept calls to Backbone.Model.set and preprocess attribute values.
 * 
 * If the model has a <code>preprocess</code> property, that property will be
 * used for mapping attribute names to preprocessor functions. This is useful
 * for automatically converting strings to numbers, for instance.
 * 
 * @param Backbone
 *            the global Backbone object.
 */
(function(Backbone) {
    var originalSet = Backbone.Model.prototype.set;
    _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {
        set: function(key, val, options) {
            if(!this.preprocess) {
                return originalSet.apply(this, arguments);
            }

            // If-else copied from Backbone source
            if (typeof key === 'object') {
                attrs = key;
                options = val;
            } else {
                (attrs = {})[key] = val;
            }

            for(attr in this.preprocess) {
                if(_.has(attrs, attr)) {
                    attrs[attr] = this.preprocess[attr](attrs[attr]);
                }
            }
            return originalSet.call(this, attrs, options);
        },
    });
})(Backbone);
```

After this, models with a `preprocess` property will use it to map attribute names to preprocessor functions. For instance, `preprocess: { age: parseInt }` means that whenever the `age` attribute is set, the value will be passed through `parseInt` before actually setting it. Attributes with no corresponding `preprocess` entry will not be affected.

Example usage:

```
var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({
    preprocess: {
        mass: parseInt,
        created: function(s) { return new Date(s); },
    },
});
var t = new Thing({
    label: '42',
    mass: '42',
    created: '1971-02-03T12:13:14+02:00',
});
console.log(t.get('label')+3); // 423
console.log(t.get('mass')+3); // 45
console.log(t.get('created').toLocaleString('ja-JP', { weekday: 'short' })); // 水
```

### Pros

- The functionality is available in all models without needing to duplicate code
- No need to send `{ validate: true }` in every call to `set`
- No need to duplicate preprocessing in `validate`, since this happens before `validate` is called (this might also be a con, se below)

### Cons

- Some duplication of Backbone code
- Might break validation since preprocessing happens before `validate` is called. JavaScript parsing methods usually return invalid values instead of throwing exceptions, though (i.e. `parseInt('foo')` returns `NaN`), so you should be able to detect that instead.